# Why does my VBA code not copy and paste when sheet is not active?

Tags: excel, vba

After much Googling and searching the net I have been unable to determine what is going wrong with my code.

If I run the following code on the XXXXX Sheet, the last row is copied and pasted in the row below with no issues:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim EndRow

EndRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A" & EndRow, "M" & EndRow).Copy Range("A" & EndRow + 1, "M" & EndRow + 1)

End Sub
```

However, I need to run the code from a different tab and have the following formula which does not work. The button is clicked and nothing is copy and pasted:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim EndRow
EndRow = Sheets("XXXXX").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("XXXXX")

.Range("A" & EndRow, "M" & EndRow).Copy Range("A" & EndRow + 1, "M" & EndRow + 1)

End With
End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong???

Thanks for your help.

Comment: On your second sub, your second `Range` (paste destination) is not qualified with a sheet so it is defaulting to the active sheet most likely

Comment: Which sheet is constant? The sheet you are copying from or the sheet you are pasting to?

Comment: I thought using With Sheets("XXXXX") meant that all ranges below referred to that Sheet? What do you mean by which sheet is constant? I am copying and pasting on the same sheet, but the button to do this will be located on a separate sheet (there is a lot more code however this is the only section causing me grief)

Comment: Right after `.Copy` your range is not qualified. To use the `With` block you need to prefix all objects with `.`

Comment: @urdearboy, my apologies, it worked! .Range on the paste section fixed the problem. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

All objects that should point to the `With` block need to be prefixed with a `.`. Your second instance of `Range` is missing this. So,

```
.Range("A" & EndRow, "M" & EndRow).Copy Range("A" & EndRow + 1, "M" & EndRow + 1)
```

goes to

```
.Range("A" & EndRow, "M" & EndRow).Copy .Range("A" & EndRow + 1, "M" & EndRow + 1)
```